# Use Excel VBA to create folder and upload image from weblink?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for ways to use excel to create a folder system for about 12000 entries, the MkDir function seems easy enough, but I'm stuck on how I'd get the rest to work. Any suggestions would be helpful

What I'm thinking:

```
IndexID | Image
1       | sampleimage.com/images.jpg
2       | sampleimage.com/image.jpg
3       | sampleimage.com/moreimages.jpg
3       | sampleimage.com/evenmoreimages.jpg
```

Would turn into this file structure:

```
%dir%\Images\1\images.jpg
%dir%\Images\2\image.jpg
%dir%\Images\3\moreimages.jpg
%dir%\Images\3\evenmoreimages.jpg
```

Or This:

```
%dir%\Images\1\1.jpg
%dir%\Images\2\1.jpg
%dir%\Images\3\1.jpg
%dir%\Images\3\2.jpg
```

I'd like to use VBA to download these files if they haven't been downloaded already and saved to the appropriate folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/beb6fa0e-fbc8-49df-9f2e-30f85d941fad/

They show how to download files from the web using an API. For setting up the directory structure and putting it all together (this code won't run yet...you have to add the API declarations):

```
Option Explicit

' api declarations go here
' ...


Const directory As String = "C:\Images"

Sub BacardiAndColaDoItDoIt()
    Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim theFolderPath As String, theFilePath As String
    Dim fileName As String

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    iLastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' create first directory
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir directory
    On Error GoTo 0

    For i = 2 To iLastRow
        theFolderPath = directory & "\" & sh.Cells(i, 1).Value
        fileName = Mid(sh.Cells(i, 2).Value, InStrRev(sh.Cells(i, 2).Value, "/") + 1, Len(sh.Cells(i, 2).Value))
        theFilePath = theFolderPath & "\" & fileName

        ' create subdirectory
        On Error Resume Next
        MkDir theFolderPath
        On Error GoTo 0

        'DownloadFile(sh.Cells(i,2).value, theFilePath)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly for downloading the file, I do not see a place where I can add a variable to rename the file automatically. (if I wanted everything to be renamed to A2:A5 .extension.
Am I going to have to have a followup script scrub the folders and rename the files after the download? or is this something I can do as it downloads?

Comment: Figured it out, added:Call DownloadFile(sh.Cells(i, 2).Value, theFilePath)
        fileExtention = Right(fileName, 4)
        newFilePath = theFolderPath & "\" & sh.Cells(i, 1).Value & fileExtention
        Name theFilePath As newFilePath